# Как подписи в chart сделать буквами?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть словарь Dictionary в котором хранятся буквы и их количество в тексте.
Мне нужно, чтобы слева значений графика были названия букв, вместо абстрактных цифр. По оси Ox всё хорошо, проблема с подписями Oy.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
    Dictionary<string, int> Data = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    Data.Add("A", 15);
    Data.Add("B", 12);
    Data.Add("C", 3);
    Data.Add("D", 27);
    Data.Add("E", 20);
    Data.Add("F", 19);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Data.ToList();
    foreach(var r in Data)
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(r.Key, r.Value);;
    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Премного благодарен